External monitor sound -- shows in aplay, but not in pipewire
As the title states - I have an external monitor (two, actually) which support audio via DisplayPort, but I am not able to play any sound through them.
I have a laptop, which is connected to multiple external monitors via a Thunderbolt docking station.  Two of the monitors support audio via DisplayPort.  I have confirmed that the hardware works in Windows -- I see both monitors show up under sound devices, and I can pick them and play sound through them with no problem.
On Ubuntu, however, the only sound output available (in the KDE settings and in pavucontrol) is the laptop's built-in speakers/headphones.
ALSA can see the monitors:
anthony@am-fn-ubuntu:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC289 Analog [ALC289 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [Y25-25]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [XV272U V3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

The HDMI 0 [Y25-25] and HDMI 1 [XV272U V3] lines correspond to my external monitors.
The do not show up in the pavucontrol GUI, and they do not show up in wpctl.
anthony@am-fn-ubuntu:~$ wpctl status
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [1.0.5, anthony@am-fn-ubuntu, cookie:2177314703]
 └─ Clients:
        32. Firefox                             [1.0.5, anthony@am-fn-ubuntu, pid:6170]
        33. libcanberra                         [1.0.5, anthony@am-fn-ubuntu, pid:3165]
        34. xdg-desktop-portal                  [1.0.5, anthony@am-fn-ubuntu, pid:3013]
        35. WirePlumber                         [1.0.5, anthony@am-fn-ubuntu, pid:18124]
        36. WirePlumber [export]                [1.0.5, anthony@am-fn-ubuntu, pid:18124]
        67. Plasma PA                           [1.0.5, anthony@am-fn-ubuntu, pid:3165]
        68. wpctl                               [1.0.5, anthony@am-fn-ubuntu, pid:18922]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      49. HD Webcam C615                      [alsa]
 │      50. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *   58. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 0.40]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │      57. HD Webcam C615 Mono                 [vol: 1.00]
 │  *   59. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │      43. HD Webcam C615                      [v4l2]
 │      44. HD Webcam C615                      [v4l2]
 │      45. Integrated_Webcam_HD                [v4l2]
 │      46. Integrated_Webcam_HD                [v4l2]
 │      47. Integrated_Webcam_HD                [v4l2]
 │      48. Integrated_Webcam_HD                [v4l2]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │      51. HD Webcam C615 (V4L2)              
 │  *   53. Integrated_Webcam_HD (V4L2)        
 │      55. Integrated_Webcam_HD (V4L2)        
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:

It seems that there's some disconnect between ALSA and PipeWire, but I haven't been able to find any reason why.
EDIT - additional info:
This is an installation of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (/etc/issue says Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS \n \l).  I installed Ubuntu using the ISO from ubuntu.com, then installed KDE afterwards.  (I did not use a Kubuntu ISO).
Pipewire version:
anthony@am-fn-ubuntu:~$ pipewire --version
pipewire
Compiled with libpipewire 1.0.5
Linked with libpipewire 1.0.5

Wireplumber version:
anthony@am-fn-ubuntu:~$ wireplumber --version
wireplumber
Compiled with libwireplumber 0.4.17
Linked with libwireplumber 0.4.17

Hardware info:
anthony@am-fn-ubuntu:~$ lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
0000:00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller #1 (rev 05)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 01)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 05)
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 05)
0000:00:07.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev 05)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 05)
0000:00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (rev 05)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 11)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Shared SRAM (rev 11)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 11)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 11)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Management Engine Interface (rev 11)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43be (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation WM590 LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SMBus Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SPI Controller (rev 11)
0000:01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] (rev a1)
0000:02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
0000:03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
0000:03:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
0000:04:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
0000:74:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
10000:e0:01.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation RST VMD Managed Controller
10000:e0:01.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a07 (rev 05)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Gold P31/BC711/PC711 NVMe Solid State Drive

